# How to wait until all recursive function calls executed by forEach loop are finished

Tags: javascript

How can I wait at the desired place in the code until all the processing on `treeData` is finished?

```
var treeData = $scope.rawData;

if ($scope.treeExpanded) {
  //expand tree
  if (treeData && treeData.children) {
    treeData.children.forEach(toggleAll);
  }

  //how to wait here until all recursion calls are finished?
  //console.log(treeData) will show a non modified object equals to $scope.rawData

}

function toggle(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  }
}

function toggleAll(d) {
  if (d && d.children) {
    d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
    toggle(d);
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518381/proper-way-to-wait-for-one-function-to-finish-before-continuing

Comment: use callback functions. You can visit this [link](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/) to know about callbacks.

Comment: Have a look at [*promises* on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). No IE support though.

Comment: @Pingbeat @Shubham I took a look at the concept of callbacks. But I have difficulties to adopt the approach of callbacks to my example, due to the nested recursive calls of `toggleAll()`. Which function should I give the callback and when should I execute the callback?

Answer (score 0):

1. Simplest way is to add a function call counter
2. On execution of all your function calls, use your callback and proceed   further.

```js
var treeData = $scope.rawData, callCompleted;

if ($scope.treeExpanded) {
  //expand tree
  if (treeData && treeData.children) {
    callsCompleted = 0;
    treeData.children.forEach(toggleAll);
  }

  //how to wait here until all recursion calls are finished?
  //console.log(treeData) will show a non modified object equals to $scope.rawData

}

function toggleCompleted() {
    // Do your processing here...
}

function toggle(d, noOfCalls, callBack) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
    callsCompleted += 1;
    if(noOfCalls === callsCompleted) {
        // all calls are completed
        callBack();
    }
  }
}

function toggleAll(d) {
  if (d && d.children) {
    d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
    toggle(d, d.length, trackToggleCompletion);
  }
}
```