# Functions are not waiting until they are resolved

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I'm trying to execute functions one at a time, sequentially. Using promises, I believe it should work, but for me, it does not work. I've researched somewhat and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518381/proper-way-to-wait-for-one-function-to-finish-before-continuing), and one of the answers explains to use Promises, that is what I've been trying to do.

Here's the functions:

```
async function loadCommands () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let commands = 0;
    readdir('./commands/', (error, files) => {
      if (error) reject(error);
      for (const file of files) {
        if (!file.endsWith('.js')) return;
        commands++;
      }
    }
    resolve(commands); // this is in my code, I forgot to put it - sorry commenters
  });
};

async function loadEvents () {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    let events = 0;
    readdir('./events/', (error, files) => {
      if (error) reject (error);
      for (const file of files) {
        if (!file.endsWith('.js')) return;
        events++
      }
    });
    resolve(events);
  });
};
```

I am then using await in an async function to try and make sure it each function resolves before going onto the next function:

```
console.log('started');
const events = await loadEvents();
console.log(events);
console.log('load commands');
const commands = await loadCommands();
console.log(commands);
console.log('end')
```

In the console, this is linked (keep in mind, I have no files in `./events/` and I have one file in `./commands/`):

```
start
0 // expected
load commands
0 // not expected, it's supposed to be 1
end
```

What am I doing wrong? I want these functions to be run sequentially. I've tried making it so instead of functions, it's just the bare code in the one async function, but still came to the issue.

Comment: You never `resolve()` the promise that you create in `loadCommands`

Comment: @ADyson Yes, you missed the point. Promises are used when dealing with asynchronous results, sequential (`then`) or concurrent (`all`)

Comment: `readdir` isn't bound to the promise properly.

Comment: `readdir()` needs to end with `resolve(commands);`

Comment: @Bergi sorry was speed-reading and missed the calls to readdir() making it necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never `resolve()` the promise that you create in `loadCommands`, and you `resolve()` the promise that you create in `loadEvents` before the `readdir` callback happened.

Also, don't do any logic in non-promise callbacks. Use the `new Promise` constructor only to [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572), and call only `resolve`/`reject` in the async callback:

```
function readdirPromise(path) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        readdir(path, (err, files) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(files);
        });
    });
});
```

or [simply](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)

```
import { promisify } from 'util';
const readdirPromise = promisify(readdir);
```

Then you can use that promise in your actual logic function:

```
async function countJsFiles(path) {
    const files = await readdirPromise(path);
    let count = 0;
    for (const file of files) {
        if (file.endsWith('.js'))
            count++;
        // I don't think you really wanted to `return` otherwise
    }
    return count;
}
function loadCommands() {
    return countJsFiles('./commands/');
}
function loadEvents() {
    return countJsFiles('./events/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use *await* outside *async*. You can `await` a promise only inside an *async* function. The functions returning promises ( here `loadCommands` & `loadEvents` ) don't need to be async. Make an *async* wrapper function like `run` and call the *await* statements inside it like this.

**PS:** Plus you also need to resolve `loadCommands` with commands in the callback itself. Same for `loadEvents`. Also, remove the return and simple increment the variable when true.

```
 function loadCommands() {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       let commands = 0;
       readdir('./commands/', (error, files) => {
           if (error) reject(error);
           for (const file of files) {
             if (file.endsWith('.js')) commands++;
           }
         }
       resolve(commands);
       });
   };

   function loadEvents() {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       let events = 0;
       readdir('./events/', (error, files) => {
         if (error) reject(error);
         for (const file of files) {
           if (file.endsWith('.js')) events++
         }
         resolve(events);
       });

     });
   };

   async function run() {
     console.log('started');
     const events = await loadEvents();
     console.log(events);
     console.log('load commands');
     const commands = await loadCommands();
     console.log(commands);
     console.log('end')
   }

   run();
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: You also need to change the `return` into a `continue` or `break` for this to work. Best don't mess with program logic in promisification code.

Comment: Hello there, this answer was mixed with the accepted one to make my final solution, thank you. I did not realize return breaks the loop, and I learned from this code - thanks.