# JS events in series & parallel

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, timer

I have a set of events, each one runs on its own timer. I have multiple use cases but for simplicity let's say they are for individual animation events.  Some events run for a specific amount of time, and some for a certain number of iterations.

I want to call events in sequence using callbacks, so that I can be sure the previous task has finished before it kicks off the next.  Add animations I also want to be able to pass parameters to the tasks so that I can control speed for example.  I would end up with something like:

```
runSequence( task1(10, 3,"test"), task5(3,7), task3())
```

Note: each task() function has it's own setInterval() timer that performs an action.

So I can run group of tasks in sequence in an order of my choosing, each task waiting for the previous one to complete before starting.   I could also initiate a different sequence of tasks like 1 second later that would be running in parallel with the first sequence.

```
runSequence( task1(10, 3,"test"), task5(3,7), task3())
wait(1000) // the previous sequence is still running even after this wait period.
runSequence (task2(), task4(5,7)). //these tasks happen in order
```

I am unsure how to achieve this.  I may be able to come up with something  that works but may not be elegant or the best practice way to do it.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: so the tasks you that pass to runSequence happen one-after-the-other, but multiple calls of runSequence can happen simultaneously?

Comment: you can use async/await -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/51894627/8851062

Comment: @TKol that is correct.

Comment: @Zrna i will check that out thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to make functions that return functions that return promises. Async promises return functions, so this might be the answer you're looking for:

Let's start with `task1(10, 3,"test")`:

```
function task1(duration, distance, elementId) {
    return async () => {
        // do some logic here with your arguments, setting animations going
        // if you want to do it dirty, just await the duration argument
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, duration));
    }
}
```

Now if you have many such functions structured similarly to above - functions that return functions that return promises - then you're ready to start defining your runSequence function

Something like so:

```
async function runSequence(sequence) {
    const results = [];
    for (let func of sequence) {
        const result = await func();
        results.push(result);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Which will then allow you to do something like

```
runSequence([task1(10, 3,"test"), task1(50, 2,"test2"), task1(15, 15,"test3")])
```

Each task passed to runSequence will happen in order, but two separate runSequence calls can be made to make two separate sequences happen simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will give this a go and see if it works for me.