# Async Javascript with MongoDB -

Tags: javascript, mongodb, async-await, async.js

I have two functions on my backend that essentially do the following:

```
const function2 = async(var1, var2, var3, var4) => {
  var x = await function1(var1);
  console.log(x);
}
var function1 = async function (var1){
  var array = [];
  var1.forEach(async function(val){
    try{
      smallarr = await Item.find({
        val:val.x
      })
      array.push(smallarr);
    }
  })
  console.log(array);
  return array;
}
```

However, the log statement in the function2 is getting called before the log statement in function1. I'm going off of the following example from an [old StackExchange thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518381/proper-way-to-wait-for-one-function-to-finish-before-continuing)

[Example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdwwk.png)

What is going wrong in my code? What am I not understanding about async/await? I can provide the actual code instead of the cute example, but they're pretty big functions.

Answer (score 2):

The `forEach` call is not waiting, its callback is an async function that returns promises, but those are not awaited. Its return value is going into the void. By consequence, `console.log(array);` is executed before the array is populated with values.

You can fix this by using a normal `for` loop. NB: a `try` without a `catch` is not very useful (and would need a `finally`), so you could just leave that out.

```
for (let val of var1) {
    smallarr = await Item.find({ val:val.x })
    array.push(smallarr);
}
```

Comment: You can add the async keyword to the variable and it will work: myArray.forEach(async x => await DBModel.create({something: x}))

Comment: @Daniel, you just repeat the code-pattern of the Asker, and the problem associated with it: the `forEach` call will not await the promises that are created in the callback given to it. My answer actually explains this, so I think you missed the point.

Comment: It does seem to be waiting, and it does work. I think you could give it a test.

Comment: No, Daniel, it doesn't work reliably. That's why the Asker asked the question -- because it doesn't (always) work like that. `forEach` is synchronous.