# Asynchronously wait for a function to be called

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I'm using the bing-maps JS control and API in WebKit (Android) and WKWebView (iOS).

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {});
// Binding the event
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'viewchangeend', function () { console.log('mapViewchangeend'); });
```

Later in the code I have a call to [map.setView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-concepts/map/change-the-map-view). Because this method is asynchronous I need to wait for the event handler to call the function above.

```
function SetMapViewLocations(pointsToView) {
  try {
    if (pointsToView.length === 1) {
      map.setView({ center: pointsToView[0], zoom: 17 });
    } else {
      var locationRect = window.Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(
        pointsToView
      );
      locationRect.height =
        locationRect.height < MIN_BOUNDS_SIZE
          ? MIN_BOUNDS_SIZE
          : locationRect.height;
      locationRect.width =
        locationRect.width < MIN_BOUNDS_SIZE
          ? MIN_BOUNDS_SIZE
          : locationRect.width;
      map.setView({ bounds: locationRect });
      // I need to wait without blocking for the viewchangeend associated method to be called before exiting the method.

    }
  } catch (exception) {
    SetJavascriptException(exception);
  }
}
```

in c# I would have set an AutoResetEvent in the callback handler method and awaited for it right after calling map.setView(...).

What are my options in Javascript?

I can't see how Promises would help here because I do not see how to construct one in my case.

Comment: _"I need to wait ... before exiting the method"_ - Why? ([What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: because otherwise, the map has not changed yet and subsequent operations would be ran in the previous result of map.setView. I can't see why added that information would add value to help how to solve this synchronisation problem.

Comment: Found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518381/proper-way-to-wait-for-one-function-to-finish-before-continuing?noredirect=1&lq=1)