# Wait for an external JS function before continuing the same method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise, wait

I have a simple JS function defined like this :

```
function firstFunction() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/path/to/my/endpoint",
        type: "GET"
    }).done(function (data) {
        localStorage.setItem("myItem", data);
    });
}
```

Later on, I have another function defined like this :

```
function mySecondFunction() {
    if(localStorage.getItem("myItem") == null) {
        // Here I want to call firstFunction() and stop everything until it finishes
    }

    //Immediately use localStorage.getItem("myItem") for other purposes
    //no matter I entered the if() or not
}
```

With a simple `async: false` in `$.ajax`, it works, but I've seen it's going to be deprecated and **I want to avoid this solution**.

Could you please suggest how to wait for `mySecondFunction` when entering my `if()` ?

I tried with `$.when()` but without success, maybe I did somehting wrong ?

I tried something like

```
   function mySecondFunction() {
      var deferred = $.Deferred();

      if(localStorage.getItem("myItem") == null) {
           $.when(firstFunction()).then(function () {
                    deferred.resolve();
                })
      }
      else {
         deferred.resolve();
      }

      //other instructions
    }
```

But `other instructions` are called BEFORE the end of `firstFunction()`

Comment: You don't "wait". You can put the functionality in a callback or use Promises.

Comment: I would recommend using promises.

Comment: @DerekLawrence  I tried using $.Deferred();, then resolve it afer the call to firstFunction() but it doesn't wait ; maybe I did something wrong ?

Comment: @Pointy you're right, but please take a look to my edit, it's what I tried but it looks incorrect (at least as I wrote it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper way to wait for one function to finish before continuing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518381/proper-way-to-wait-for-one-function-to-finish-before-continuing)

Comment: Please don't add titles like *EDIT* to your question; Anyone can view the edit history of your question if it interests them.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Interesting, I'm gonna take a look. Surprisingly I haven't found this question during my searches... Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `firstFunction()` return a promise.

```js
function firstFunction() {
    return new Promise((res, err) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/path/to/my/endpoint",
            type: "GET"
        }).done(function (data) {
            localStorage.setItem("myItem", data);
            res()
        });
    });
}
```

Make `mySecondFunction` aysnc.

```js
async function mySecondFunction() {
    if(localStorage.getItem("myItem") == null) {
        await firstFunction();
    }

    localStorage.getItem("myItem")
    ...
}
```

This is how I would recommend you do this, since the ajax request wont block execution of other code, like button callbacks. Async/await and promises are hard to grasp at first, so here's some reading on how they work behind the scenes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: YOu can allso do firstFuction,then( () => { secondFunction(); } ); calls.then when the promise is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `if` clauses with a `while` loop and call your `firstFunction` in that loop.

Example:

```
function mySecondFunction() {
    while(localStorage.getItem("myItem") == null) {
        firstFunction()
    }
}
```