# Reading and sending data to user in sequence in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm coding website in node.js using express and socket.io.
The server is sending to user photo and data from every file in directory using *socket.emit* function.

The problem with this code: The server is sending data from 2 files but **image in second emit is same as first** beacouse before sends first img is changing data of first file to second data.

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55698897/18325551) but it's not working. Some of the server side code:

```
function send(file) {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                fs.readFile(dir + file, 'utf8', (err, jsonString) => {

                    jsonString = JSON.parse(jsonString);

                    buffer = ""
                    img = false

                    img_path = dir + jsonString.number

                    if (fs.existsSync(img_path + '.jpg')) {

                        fs.readFile(img_path + '.jpg', function (err, buf) {
                            buffer = buf
                            img = true
                        });
                    }
                    if (fs.existsSync(img_path + '.png')) {

                        fs.readFile(img_path + '.png', function (err, buf) {
                            buffer = buf
                            img = true
                        });
                    }

                    setTimeout(() => { // <---- Without wait buffer will be blank

                        console.log(img_path) //both times is same
                        data = {
                            number: jsonString.number,
                            image: img,
                            buffer: buffer.toString('base64')
                        }

                        socket.emit('data', data)
                        console.log("sended!")
                        resolve()
                    }, 100)

                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        return;
                    }
                });
    })
}

async function files() {

  fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
      if (err) {
          throw err
      }

      files.forEach(async file => {
      
          if (file.split('.').pop() == 'json') {
             await send(file)
          }
       })
   })
}

files()
```

**But this is not working. Thanks for help!**

Comment: `fs.readFile()` is async, you are using it like `fs.readFileSync()`. You could change the readFile to readFileSync but you actually have to restucture the code to handle async properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few misconceptions that have to addressed:

- async and sync flows used in same context, that's why you needed a `setTimeout`
- async function in forEach doesn't do what you expect
- variable management, use `let` or `const`

Some small things:

- argument passing, `dir` wasn't available in some contexts
- async function definition for `send`

For example your code could be rewritten like this:
*Do note that I did not run this program*

```js
const { promisify } = require("util");
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);
const exists = promisify(fs.exists);
const readdir = promisify(fs.readdir);

async function getBuffer(filePath) {
  const isFile = await exists(filePath);
  if (!isFile) return;
  return readFile(filePath);
}

async function send(dir, file) {
  const content = await readFile(file, 'utf8');

  if (!content) return;

  const json = JSON.parse(content);
  const img_path = dir + json.number;

  const buf1 = await getBuffer(`${img_path}.jpg`);
  const buf2 = await getBuffer(`${img_path}.png`);

  console.log(img_path);
  const data = {
    number: json.number,
    image: buf1 || buf2,
    buffer: (buf1 || buf2).toString('base64'),
  }
  socket.emit('data', data);
  console.log("sended!");
}

async function files(dir) {
  const files = await readdir(dir);
  for (const file in files) {
    if (file.split('.').pop() === 'json') {
      await send(dir, file);
    }
  }
}

files("<directory>");
```

Comment: Thanks! I know my code is not perfect but I'm still learning js. When i run this there is any errors, but it isn't sending. It's stopping on `for (const file in files) {` line. `console.log(files)` returns `Promise { <pending> }`. I provided appropriate directory but I don't know how to solve this

Comment: @PioterSky Great that you're learning! The only help I can give is break down the larger problem into smaller, more manageable problems.

Comment: Help with these smaller, more manageable problems can be asked on StackOverflow!