# Fetch-function gets called at the end of the code

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm a beginner in javascript, but did a lot of googling to figure out promises and async/await. However, it seems like the fetch function call gets called at the end the very end of my program and i don't know how to fix it. I have tried multiple versions of this function from stackoverflow but it seems nothing is giving me the expected result.. What do i do wrong?

This would be my fetch function:

```
async function fetchData() {
    const resp = await fetch("/test.csv");
    const data = await resp.text();
    return data;
}
function processData(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

Whith this call:

```
console.log("Before Fetch")
fetchData().then(processData)
console.log("Code after Fetch")
```

I would expect the following output:

```
Before Fetch
data
Code after Fetch
```

But i get:

```
Before Fetch
Code after Fetch
data
```

A weird fix would be to put my entire code in the processData(data) function, but there has to be another way i guess?

Comment: That is why you pass `processData` as a function to the `.then()`, instead of invoking it separately after `fetchData()`. Because it is a function that is invoked once the response is back in while the rest of the code continues.

Comment: You have come to the point that every beginner needs to face once: understand and get to terms with *asynchronous execution*…

Comment: Take a look at “await” in asynchronous JavaScript :)

Comment: You can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21518470/19533962)