# How can call DOMContentLoaded inside function after the deviceready event fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, frontend, cordova-plugins

currently functionB is called before onDeviceReady**functionA** but i want to call functionB  after the onDeviceReady**functionA** cordova plugin response.

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReadyfunctionA, false);

 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {functionB();});
```

Comment: Hmm, Perhaps create a function that calls both, but wait for the 1st one to complete using using [Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55698897/4935162)?

Comment: sorry i am calling functiona-cordova method in device ready  and functionb is javascript function could you please guide with above code

Comment: How we can use the deviceready &  DOMContentLoaded

Answer (score 0):

Assuming onDeviceReadyFunctionA is an async function/returns a promise you could do:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReadyC, false);

function onDeviceReadyC() {
    onDeviceReadyfunctionA().then(functionB)
}
```

Or you could do something similar with async/await:

```
async function onDeviceReady() {
    await onDeviceReadyfunctionA()
    functionB()
  }
```

sideNote: I think this is the syntax you're looking for with functionB:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", functionB);
  function functionB(event) {
    console.log(event)
  }
```

If you want to use it inline, I'd use an arrow function:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {console.log(event)});
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Mister_CK.  I have one query some pages device ready function return quicker response and some pages DOMContentLoaded inside function B qucier. how to implement the async for DOMContentLoaded  and deviceready function

Comment: why do you want to listen to both, are they triggering different things? I don't think you can make DOMContentLoaded and deviceReady themselves asynchronous. But instead the functions that they trigger should be asynchronous. I would only use the onDeviceReady listener and then put then let then call functionA and then Function B from inside the same function as in the first snippet. Or is there a specific reason that you want to use both?

Comment: yes correct, function A and function B triggering different things. device ready calling the cordova method via  functiona A.  DOMContentLoad need to trigger for the Appdynamic js(functionB will collect the page title , page url and other information and pass to Appdynamic in  DOMContentLoad)

Comment: when i use the device ready also, still cordova plugin response getting null in the DOContentnLoaded.

Comment: android cordova getting called device ready but iOS is giving null