# Why is my DIV refresh not working on mobile device?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am refreshing my DIVs from another page. It is sort of working... Here is what I use:

```
 function scheduleReload() {
     $('#imageContainer').load('Monday.php');

  }
  setInterval(scheduleReload,500);
```

It does reload/refresh the DIVs but it's fairly slow although I use only 5 ms to reload but the script that is reloaded from the PHP page is pretty long, so might be that reason. Anyway, it shows the correct content on my website on a computer. If I load it on a tablet or phone, its not showing. How is that possible?

Maybe here the HTML I am using:

```html
 <div align="center">
    <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2"  >
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><font face="Verdana" size="3" color="#FF0000" ><b><span class="blinking" id="Container3"></span></b></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
               <div id="Container1></div>
            </td>
            <td valign="middle">
                <div>
                    <span style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 20px;">
                    <b> <span id="Container2"></span></b>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: could be not enough memory to display it?

Comment: Reloading every half second `setInterval(scheduleReload,500);` but what if the prior load has not completed? Use a Promise perhaps?

Comment: The 500 you pass to `setInterval` is 500 milliseconds, not 5 milliseconds. Still, quite aggressive for mobile speeds unless everyone is using 5G in a city where everyone else is on break...

Comment: Protip: never use `setInterval` without some kind of safety baked in. If anything goes wrong, now you're running something that goes wrong every 500 milliseconds with no way to stop it.  Either capture your `setInterval` id so you can call `clearInterval` on it, or use a function that calls itself on a `setTimeout` as last line, so that if anything goes wrong, the loop stops. And on a practical note: don't refresh a div every half second, give people some time to see your content before you update it. And better yet: only update it when the user's actions suggest it might be a good time.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thank you for helping with the formatting. I just learn how to use this site here.

Comment: Lots of Promise examples on here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55698897/125981

OR a whole list of them https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=JavaScript+Promise

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss thank you for that tip. I didn't really know how to write my question. I tried of course first to look it up. I was able to resolve some of my problem thanks to this amazing site.

Comment: Idea of a Promise is that you wait for the request to finish THEN wait (using `setTimeout` perhaps to update N time later - like 10 seconds with `10000` value